# ImageJ API: how to update FileInfo when saving ImagePlus.GRAY16 instance as Jpeg?

Tags: java, imagej

I use ImageJ API in my java development work. I would like to use [ij.io.FileSaver.saveAsJpeg(String path)](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/io/FileSaver.html#saveAsJpeg-java.lang.String-) method to save an `ImagePlus` instance as a Jpeg file. My method call looks like this:

```
new FileSaver(myImagePlusInstance).saveAsJpeg(myPathToFile);
```

However, I have a problem with the `saveAsJpeg(String path)` method. For some reason (that I do not know) its implementation when saving `ImagePlus.GRAY16` and `ImagePlus.GRAY32` image instances explicitly excludes them from updating their corresponding `FileInfo` object instances. Here is the corresponding ImageJ source code:

```
/** Save the image in JPEG format using the specified path.
    @see #setJpegQuality
    @see #getJpegQuality
*/
public boolean saveAsJpeg(String path) {
    String err = JpegWriter.save(imp, path, jpegQuality);
    if (err==null && !(imp.getType()==ImagePlus.GRAY16 || imp.getType()==ImagePlus.GRAY32))
        updateImp(fi, FileInfo.GIF_OR_JPG);
    return true;
}
```

I need to save images of type `ImagePlus.GRAY16` as Jpeg. Further in my java application I have to use `getOriginalFileInfo().directory` field for my `ImagePlus` instances.

What is the correct way to update the `FileInfo` object instance (in particular, its `directory` field) when saving an `ImagePlus.GRAY16` image as Jpeg file using ImageJ API?

Comment: I have asked the same question on [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/fileinfo-update-when-saving-imageplus-gray16-instance-as-jpeg/3511), but have got no reply there since 3 weeks already.

Comment: I responded on the ImageJ forum.